# How below REGEXP_REPLACE works?

Tags: oracle

I have query in my project and that is having `REGEXP_REPLACE`
i tried to find how it works by searching but i found it like

> w+ Matches a word character (that is, an alphanumeric or underscore
>   (_) character).

but not able to find `'"\w+\":'` why these `""` are used and what is mean by `'{|}|"',''`

```
UPDATE (SELECT data,data_value FROM  TEMP) t
SET t.DATA_VALUE=REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(t.data, '"\w+\":',''),'{|}|"','');
```

can you please tell me how it works?

Comment: There're multiple questions here. Please, [read the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix001.htm#SQLRF55540) (look for `|` and `\ `) and then experiment with `regexp_replace` on the sample data.

Comment: Also, check out [this useful script](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl), that "explains" regular expressions, for example: your [first](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%22%5Cw%2B%5C%22%3A) and [second](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%7B%7C%7D%7C%22) expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appear to be a regular expression for stripping keys and enclosing brackets from a JSON string - unfortunately, if this is the case then it does not work in all situations.

The regular expression

```
'"\w+\":'
```

will match:

- A `"` double quotation mark;
- `\w+` one-or-more word (`a-z` or `A-Z` or `0-9` or `_`) characters;
- `\"` another double quotation mark - *note: the `\` character is not necessary*; then
- A `:` colon.

So:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
  '{"key":"value","key2":"value with \"quote"}',
  '"\w+":',   -- Pattern matched
  ''          -- Replacement string
)
```

Will output:

```
{"value","value with \"quote"}
```

The second pattern `{|}|"` will match either a `{`, or a `}` or a `"` character (and could have been equivalently written as `[{}"]`) so:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
  '{"value","value with \"quote"}',
  '{|}|"',    -- Pattern matched
  ''          -- Replacement string
)
```

Will output:

```
value,value with \quote
```

Which is fine, until (like my example) you have an escaped double quote (or curly braces) in the value string; in which case those will also get stripped leaving the escape character.

*(Note: you would not typically find this but it is possible to include escaped quotes in the key. So `{"keywith\":quote":"value"}` would get replaced to `{quote":"value"}` and then `quote:value` which is not the intended output.)*

If parsing JSON is what you are trying to do (pre-Oracle 12) then you can use:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
  '{"key":"value","key2":"value with \"quote","keywith\":quote":"value with \"{}"}',
  '^{|"(\\"|[^"])+":(")?((\\"|[^"])+?)\2((,)|})',
  '\3\6'
 )
```

Which outputs:

```
value,value with \"quote,value with \"{}
```

Or in Oracle 12 you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   JSON_TABLE(
         '{"key":"value","key2":"value with \"quote","keywith\":quote":"value with \"{}"}',
         '$.*' NULL ON ERROR
         COLUMNS (
           value VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$'
         )
       )
```

Which outputs:

```
VALUE
-----------------
value
value with "quote
value with "{}
```

Answer (score 0):

example:::REGEXP_REPLACE( string, pattern [, replacement_string [, start_position [, nth_appearance [, match_parameter ] ] ] ] )

| is or(CAN MEAN MORE THAN ONE ALTERNATIVE )  , is for at least as in {n,} at least n times

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php
"where I got my info"

'"\w+\":' why these "" are used and what is mean by '{|}|"',''
Matches a word character(\w)One or more times(+)   this has to be messed up it's missing the right quantity of close parentheses by putting \" w+ \"
they allow the " to be shown. This expression takes one expression changes it then uses that as the basis for the next change. Good luck figuring the rest out. Regular expressions aren't too bad, pretty intuitive once you get the basics down.